# Angular Background Slider using photos directly from foursquare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, background-image, foursquare

I'm working on adding some features to make my project app look better. It's an app that creates a chatroom in any building you are located nearby based on location. It is currently integrating foursquare to get the user's location, but also to get photos for the chatroom they entered (i.e. they enter a bar, it shows the first five photos that foursquare has on that bar). I want to make a background slider using angular, but I am beyond stuck on how to get it properly implemented. 
Here is my code for the chatroom template:

```
<ng-include src="'/templates/navbar.html'"></ng-include>
<div ng-repeat="photo in photos" >
  <img ng-src="{{photo.prefix}}300x300{{photo.suffix}}"></img>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row " style="padding-top:40px;">
        <h3 class="text-center">{{venue}} </h3>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    RECENT CHAT HISTORY
                </div>
                <div scroll-glue class="panel-body" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 540px;">
                    <ul class="media-list">

                        <li class="media" ng-repeat="message in messages">

                            <div class="media-body">

                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-circle" style="height: 57px; width: 88px; max-height: 57px; max-width: 88px;" ng-src="{{message.img}}" />
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <p class="chatText" ng-bind-html="message.message | emoji"></p>
                                        <br />
                                        <small class="text-muted">Posted by <b>{{message.username}}</b>, at {{message.createdAt}}</small>
                                        <hr />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <form ng-submit="createMSG(message)">
                        <div class="input-group">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="message" placeholder="Enter Message" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <span style="margin: 0 20px;" emoji-picker="message" placement="right" title="Emoji" recent-limit="12"></span>
                            <button class="btn btn-custom" type="submit">SEND</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    ONLINE USERS
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="media-list">

                        <li class="media" ng-repeat="user in users">

                            <div class="media-body">

                                <div class="media">
                                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                        <img class="media-object img-circle" style="height: 57px; width: 88px; max-height: 57px; max-width: 88px;" ng-src="{{user.img}}" />
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <h5>{{user.username}} | User </h5>

                                        <small class="text-muted" style="color: green;"><b>Online</b></small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller that allows you to check-in to the chatroom with the integrated foursquare:

```
angular.module('thesis.foursquare', ['ngRoute'])

.controller('CheckinController', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$http', 'UserService',
    function checkInCtrl($scope, $location, $window, $cookies, $rootScope, $http, UserService) {
        if (!$cookies.get('id')) {
            $location.path("/login");
        } else {
            // get users gps coords
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                $scope.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                $scope.long = position.coords.longitude;
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore/?client_id=AL4DDIM5HHXXYV1HKMQBGFLFIJRHJVPR4BI4CJ0VQIN4PHGZ&client_secret=VXRH3J0QWAJKGIPHMEIOWWR3YSADCO3S2IJQMS3BNVEDFYUE&v=20130815&ll=' + $scope.lat + ',' + $scope.long + '&radius=800'
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.venue = [];
                    $.map(response.data.response.groups[0].items, function(venues) {
                        $.map(venues, function(venue) {
                            if (venue.id) {
                                var aVenue = {};
                                aVenue.id = venue.id;
                                aVenue.name = venue.name;
                                aVenue.location = venue.location;
                                aVenue.contact = venue.contact;
                                $scope.venue.push(aVenue);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }, function error(msg) {
                alert('Please enable your GPS position future.');
            }, {
                maximumAge: 600000,
                timeout: 5000,
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });

            $scope.venue = [];
            var checkin = function() {

            };

            // url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore/?client_id=AL4DDIM5HHXXYV1HKMQBGFLFIJRHJVPR4BI4CJ0VQIN4PHGZ&client_secret=VXRH3J0QWAJKGIPHMEIOWWR3YSADCO3S2IJQMS3BNVEDFYUE&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&query=' + search + '&near=' + currentLocation

            // https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore/?client_id=AL4DDIM5HHXXYV1HKMQBGFLFIJRHJVPR4BI4CJ0VQIN4PHGZ&client_secret=VXRH3J0QWAJKGIPHMEIOWWR3YSADCO3S2IJQMS3BNVEDFYUE&v=20130815&ll=29.9407336,-90.0820647&radius=200

            $scope.joinChat = function(id, name) {
                if ($cookies.get('id')) {
                    $rootScope.venue = name;
                    $rootScope.id = id;
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/' + id + '/photos?client_id=AL4DDIM5HHXXYV1HKMQBGFLFIJRHJVPR4BI4CJ0VQIN4PHGZ&client_secret=VXRH3J0QWAJKGIPHMEIOWWR3YSADCO3S2IJQMS3BNVEDFYUE&v=20130815&ll=40.7,-74&limit=5'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        $rootScope.photos = response.data.response.photos.items;
                    });
                    UserService.joinchat(id).success(function(data) {
                        $location.path("/chatroom");
                    });
                } else {
                    $location.path("/login");
                }
            };

        }
    }
]);
```

Here is the controller for the chatroom template:

```
angular.module('thesis.chatroom', ['luegg.directives', 'emoji', 'vkEmojiPicker', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])

.controller('ChatroomController', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', '$cookies', '$rootScope', '$http', 'UserService', 'chatSocket',
    function AdminUserCtrl($scope, $location, $window, $cookies, $rootScope, $http, UserService, chatSocket) {
        if (!$cookies.get('id')) {
            $location.path("/login");
        } else {
            $scope.users = [];
            $scope.messages = [];
            $scope.id = $rootScope.id;
            var chatId = $scope.id;
            $rootScope.id = null;
            chatSocket.emit('joinedChat', {
                chatId: $scope.id
            });

            chatSocket.on('message', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.messages = data.messages;
                $scope.users = data.users;
            });

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                if ($scope.users.length === 1) {
                    chatSocket.emit('DestroyChat', {
                        idChatroom: chatId,
                        idUser: $cookies.get('id')
                    });
                    chatSocket.removeListener();
                } else {
                    chatSocket.emit('leaveChat', {
                        idUser: $cookies.get('id')
                    });
                    chatSocket.removeListener();
                }
            });

            $scope.createMSG = function(msg) {
                if ($cookies.get('id')) {
                    UserService.createMSG(msg, chatId, $cookies.get('id')).then(function(data) {});
                    $scope.message = "";
                } else {
                    $location.path("/login");
                }
            };
        }
    }
]);
```

current result:

[All images show up, but cannot figure out the angular slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaezl.png)

Any suggestions/tips/criticisms are always appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Need more information, what exactly are you having trouble with? is it how to implement sliders in general? making the slider load dynamic images? do you already have any code written for the slider? are you using any kind of plugin for the slider? Also why are you using the rootscope to store your photos?

Comment: I'm having trouble taking the photos from foursquare and implement them into an angular background slider. I tried a couple different ways, but to no avail. So I wiped that code. The images load no problem. But I can't get a slider to work.